# how to add variable into ActiveRecord :condition => ''

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, activerecord, conditional-statements

Trying to get a variable into a :condition statement.

```
user = User.all(:conditions => 'confirmed_at is NULL AND 
confirmation_sent_at <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL X day)')
```

How would one inject a variable on the X day part?
I tried proc blocks and escaping + regular but all fail

Comment: I believe you can do... `User.where('confirmed_at is NULL AND confirmation_sent_at <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ? day)', your_variable)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions

You should be able to do the follow:

```
User.where('confirmed_at is NULL AND confirmation_sent_at <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ? day)', your_variable)
```